# Slumdog millionaire (8)

Tags: knowledge

My Indian friend Jamal recently participated in the well-known TV quiz
show ***[Who wants to be a millionaire?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Wants_to_Be_a_Millionaire)***. You might have heard or read about Jamal's spectacular success; the media reported on it extensively.

Here is what Jamal told us about his 8.000 Euro question:

> We moved on to the 8.000 Euro question. Before reading it to me, Prem
>   Kumar made some tasteless joke about the monotone voice that I had been
>   using when answering his questions so far.  I was annoyed, but decided to
>   stay calm and to ignore it.
>
> I had never been to the place mentioned in the question; however, each
>   of the phrases in the four possibilities was familiar to me. I decided
>   to try and match each possibility to its correct place and hopefully
>   the one left over would be the answer.
>
> D's associated metropolis did not come to my mind right away.  With C,
>   I figured the association based on the stadium's name; this could not be
>   the right answer. Answer B also was very obvious, as that movie and its
>   associated (and somewhat annoying) song had come out a few years ago.
>   Answer A didn't ring a bell right away, so I focused closer on A and D.
>
> D's phrase brought Disneyland to mind for some reason.  My mental
>   connection was that if you are happy, then you're probably friendly as well.
>   I knew that wasn't it, though, but maybe it was some place nearby.
>   I turned to answer A and kept repeating the phrase in my mind over and
>   over again.  Suddenly a faint bell did start ringing, and brought me to
>   liberty. I said in a loud and clear voice: "My final answer is A."
>
> Prem Kumar looked at me with a very serious face, causing my heart to
>   beat faster.  "I am afraid that that is", he said, pausing for a few
>   seconds, "absolutely correct!  If you decide to stop now, you are
>   guaranteed to walk away with at least 8.000 Euros!" I breathed a sigh
>   of relief.

***What was the 8.000 Euro question?

What were the four possible answers A, B, C, D?***

Comment: something to do with life liberty and the pursuit of happiness with A being philadelphia?

Comment: I was thinking city slogans, "City of Brotherly Love", but the "stadiums", and "movie" and "song" have thrown me off track.

Comment: City slogans are the right idea.

Comment: They are US cities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is:

> Which of these is the slogan for the city of Philadelphia?

The correct answer A is:

> The City of Brotherly Love

because:

> "Suddenly a faint **bell** did start ringing, and brought me to **liberty**": The **liberty bell** is found in Philadelphia.

The other answers were

B:

> The City of Angels [Los Angeles. Also the name of 1998 movie starring Nick Cage and Meg Ryan; the song being Angel by Sarah McLachlan (thanks @irishPanda)]

C:

> The Mile High City [Denver, home to The Mile High stadium. Thanks to @Fillet for this one - I was nowhere!]

D:

> The Magic City [Sounds a bit like a ride at Disney World, but is actually the slogan for Miami, which is in Florida and not too far (in US geography terms) from Disney World in Orlando, Florida.]

Alternative idea for D:

> America's friendliest city [which is Delphos. "Delphos" has similar letters to Disney... but is a tiny place in Ohio, so unlikely to be correct]

Comment: I think C is Denver. The Mile High Stadium is in Denver, the Mile High city.

Comment: @Fillet - many thanks, I think that completes it (providing I got the others all correct)

Comment: D might be "The Friendly City", Bellflower: http://articles.latimes.com/1997-01-11/local/me-17505_1_city-clerk (Quote: There are hundreds of other U.S. cities that claim to be "The Friendly City." )

Comment: B has something to do with angels.

Comment: Well, that does make B obvious, as well as the song (which I now have stuck in my head, you evil, evil person). A and C I agree with the above, which leaves D bugging me.

Comment: The song is Angel by Sarah McLachlan. Probably most well known now as the song played at children's funerals, and as the background music to that damned commercial with all the abused puppies. (Go away Sarah McLachlan, I'm trying to eat dinner!)

Comment: That answer is good enough now. For D my answer was Athens, Tennessee (The friendly city). but there are other possibilities...